# Choosing the right design for nparLD

Tags: r, statistics, nonlinear-functions

I have to use [nparLD package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nparLD/nparLD.pdf) due to some data distribution and heteroscedasticity reasons but I have some trouble to select the right design (*F1-LD-F1* or *F2-LD-F1*).

I have two groups (one for patients and one for controls) and all participants underwent the same MR examination three times (before exercise, 30 minutes after exercise and 24 hours after exercise).

I want to see both within- and between subjects differences.

I guess it will be *F1-LD-F1* design but I need a confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but maybe it could be helpful for others.

Yes, this experiment has the F1-LD-F1 design structure with treatment (i.e. exercise/no exercise, if I understood correctly) being the whole-plot factor.